# Using a cursor in a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I want to find the min, max and average for each quarter using stored procedure and cursors. Can't figure out where am I going wrong.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE seven2
IS 
   CURSOR c1 IS 
      SELECT 
         qtrcode as QTR, 
         cast(MIN(salaryoffered) as decimal(4,2)) as MIN,  
         cast(MAX(salaryoffered) as decimal(4,2)) as MAX, 
         cast(AVG(salaryoffered) as decimal(4,2)) as AVG
      FROM 
         interview
      GROUP BY 
         qtrcode
      ORDER BY 
         qtrcode

BEGIN 
   FOR qtrcode in c1
   LOOP 
       dbms_output.put_line(min || ' ' ||max|| ' ' ||avg);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Can we add padding functions to the above query and if so how?

Comment: Define "going wrong".  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  On what line?  Off the top of my head, you're missing a semicolon after the cursor definition and before the `BEGIN`, you're trying to reference local variables `min`, `max`, and `avg` rather than elements from the `qtrcode` record (i.e. `qtrcode.min || ' ' qtrcode.max ... `), and you're using built-in function names as aliases rather than meaningful names.  Your casts also look suspect based on your data unless you're really sure that no one is ever going to be offered a salary greater than 99.99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the interview table with just 2 columns for the example purpose and inserted some dummy data, see the changes in the procedure, it works fine now

```
SQL>
SQL> desc interview
 Name                                                                     Null?    Type
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ -------- -------------------------------
 SALARYOFFERED                                                                     NUMBER(10,2)
 QTRCODE                                                                           VARCHAR2(4)

SQL>




SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE seven2
  2  IS
  3     CURSOR c1 IS
  4        SELECT
  5           qtrcode as QTR,
  6           cast(MIN(salaryoffered) as decimal(10,4)) as MIN,
  7           cast(MAX(salaryoffered) as decimal(10,4)) as MAX,
  8           cast(AVG(salaryoffered) as decimal(10,4)) as AVG
  9        FROM
 10           interview
 11        GROUP BY
 12           qtrcode
 13        ORDER BY
 14           qtrcode ;
 15
 16  BEGIN
 17     FOR qtrcode in c1
 18     LOOP
 19             dbms_output.put_line('The qtr is ' || qtrcode.qtr ||' The min sal is '|| qtrcode.min || ' The max sal is ' || qtrcode.max|| ' The avg sal is' ||qtrcode.avg);
 20     END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /

Procedure created.



SQL> exec seven2;
The qtr is Q1 The min sal is 137.07 The max sal is 964.66 The avg sal is 580.8748
The qtr is Q2 The min sal is 127.79 The max sal is 938.49 The avg sal is 550.52
The qtr is Q3 The min sal is 231.1 The max sal is 992.45 The avg sal is 672.59
The qtr is Q4 The min sal is 103.19 The max sal is 960.13 The avg sal is 431.318

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```